# as3: usage of this keyword

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am just wondering when it's necessary to use the keyword `this.somevar` instead of just `somevar`.

I usually don't use this under the following circumstances:

1. i have made a var private for a class
2. i refer to it in order to use it as a local var for that class

correct? or is this not just a style thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You generally only have to use this.varname if you are inside a function that has a parameter with the same name and you want to refer to the member variable. Whether or not the member var is private does not have any effect on having to use 'this'.

Answer (score 4):

As has already been mentioned, you don't need to use *this* in a very simple case, where you want to refer to a class member variable from a class member method, e.g.:

```
public function myClassMethod() : void
{
  // "this" is redundant here, as it is implied if omitted
  this.myPrivateOrPublicVariable = 123;
}
```

Do note though that there are cases where *this* (which is evaluated at the time it is encountered in a program, rather than at instantiation as one might guess) does not refer to the class in which it is written. More specifically, this happens when you use it inside a function that will get called using a method such as [Function.apply()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/labs/air/1/aslr/Function.html#apply()). This method allows the caller to specify the object that will be referred to by *this*, and it is commonly used in callbacks, e.g. in tweening engines.

```
// Call myFunction(listOfArguments[0], listOfArguments[1] ...), 
// with this referring to objectReferredToByThis.
myFunction.apply(objectReferredToByThis, listOfArguments);
```

Here's an example with the popular tweening engine Tweener, where the default behavior is to have *this* refer to the tweened object (i.e. the MovieClip _mc), rather than to an instance of the class in which this is written (i.e. *MyClass*).

```
package
{
  /* ... imports ... */

  public class MyClass extends Sprite
  {
     private var _mc : MovieClip;

     public function tweenSomething() : void
     {
       var tween : Object = {
         x: 0,
         time: 1, 
         onComplete: function() : void {
           // Here, "this" will not refer to the instance
           // of MyClass, but rather to the _mc MovieClip,
           // which is the object being tweened below.
           this.visible = false;
         }
       };

       Tweener.addTween(_mc, tween);
     }
  }
}
```

In the above code, the use of *this* is necessary, because we want to explicitly instruct the runtime to modify the *visible* state of our MovieClip (_mc). Had we not used *this*, the *visible* reference would have referred to *MyClass.visible*, because of function closure.

Comment: thanks for getting into the details of this.
i appreciate the clarifications.

Comment: hmm, i don't get it why in the tweener example this. refers to the movieclip.

Comment: @Richards, it does because the caller (inside Tweener) specified the tweening target to be reference by the "this" variable. See the documentation about Function.apply(). Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you use this inside an object this will refer to the object itself. Here is an example where you would use it:

```
package
{
    public class foo
    {
        private var variable:uint;

        public function foo(variable:uint)
        {
            this.variable = variable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i was saying that i think this happens anyway.
see the comment below; i found it useful.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something to add to the other answers: In ActionScript 3, you can reference member variables and functions basically two ways:

```
// 1. the normal way
obj.var = 5;
obj.func();

// 2. the auxiliary way
obj["var"] = 5;
obj["func"]();
```

This may seem pointless, but there are certain cases when, for instance, concatenating Strings into various combinations to use random, dynamically-specified variables or functions in an object can be useful, like this:

```
private function someFunc():void
{
    obj[randomFuncStr()]();
}

private function randomFuncStr():String
{
    // randomly decide on a function to call and return its name as a String
}
```

But what if you want to use Strings to access variables or functions inside of `this`?  This doesn't work:

```
"var" = 5; // error
"func"(); // error
```

So what you have to do instead is this:

```
this["var"] = 5; // the this keyword is good for something after all!
this["func"]();  // " " " " " " " " "
```

Other people have already mentioned this next reason, but the first time I ever took `this.var` or `this.func()` seriously in AS3 (and I usually still look at its usage with clear contempt) was when I was overriding `UIComponent.setLayoutBoundsSize()`, which has a parameter named `width` and a parameter named `height`.  UIComponent also uses these names as properties, and I don't like changing parameter names when overriding a method.  So saying things like `this.width = x;` or `this.height = y;` suddenly became relevant.  Aside from these two scenarios, I see no reason to use `this` when referring to a variable or function within the same object internally.

As a side note, if you're having to do this next little thing because of the way an API has been constructed or for some other really good reason (try to avoid setting things up like this yourself), occasionally you might pass `this` in as an argument to a function or something that needs a reference back to the calling object.

Answer (score 0):

How about to start using `this` keyword, first of all, cause it helps you quickly recognize whether the variable local or global (method or class owned) in the code. All you need a piece of the code where you can see `this` and then realize immediately that this is a class variable visible globally, instead of additional scrolling for the target definition.